# Is assert usable in constant expressions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, assert, constant-expression

The `assert`-macro from `<cassert>` provides a concise way of ensuring that a condition is met. If the argument evaluates to `true`, it shall not have any further effects. However, can its invocation also be used inside a constant expression in that case?

Comment: currently active [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65985)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was dealt with by [LWG 2234](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2234), which was brought back to attention after relaxed constraints on `constexpr` functions had been introduced.

> **Proposed resolution**:
>
> This wording is relative to N3936.
>
> 1. Introduce the following new definition to the existing list in 17.3
>      [definitions]:
>
>    **constant subexpression** [defns.const.subexpr]
>
>    an expression whose evaluation as subexpression of a  *conditional-expression CE* (5.16 [expr.cond]) would not prevent *CE* from being a core constant expression (5.20 [expr.const]).
> 2. Insert a new paragraph following 19.3 [assertions] p1 as indicated:
>
>    -?- An expression `assert(`*E*`)` is a constant subexpression ( [defns.const.subexpr]), if either
>
>    - `NDEBUG` is defined at the point where assert(E) appears, or
>    - *E* contextually converted to `bool` (4 [conv]), is a constant subexpression that evaluates to the value `true`.

#### Constant subexpressions

This resolution introduced the notion of a *constant subexpression* - essentially an expression that is not (necessarily) a constant expression in itself, but can be used inside one. Consider for example

```
constexpr void f() {
    int i = 0;
    ++i;
}
```

`++i` is not a constant expression as it modifies an object whose lifetime started outside that expression (§5.20/(2.15)). However, the expression `f()` is in its entirety a  constant expression, because the previous point does not apply - `i`'s lifetime starts in `f`. Hence `++i` is a constant subexpression, as `++i` does not prevent `f()` from being a constant expression.

#### And `assert`?

The second part of the resolution guarantees that `assert(`*E*`)` is a constant subexpression if either `NDEBUG` is defined or the argument is itself a constant subexpression and evaluates to `true`. This implies that a call to `assert` can also be a bog-standard constant expression.

The following is well-formed:

```
constexpr int check(bool b) {
    assert(b);
    return 7;
}
constexpr int k = check(true);
```

`b` is a constant subexpression and evaluates to `true` in the call `check(true)`, hence `assert(b)` is a constant subexpression and therefore does not prevent `check(true)` from being one.

Of course, the same pitfall as with `static_assert` in templates is possible. Given that `NDEBUG` isn't defined, this definition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required by §7.1.5/5 :

```
constexpr void fail() {
    assert(false);
}
```

Comment: The terminology is a bit weird: a *constant subexpression CS* of a *constant expression CE* does not need to be a subexpression of CE, nor does it need to be a subexpression at all (a complete expression).

Comment: @dyp A subexpression of `e` can be `e` itself, can't it? (e.g. compare §1.9/10) Or are you actually referring to the CS not being part of CE at all?

Comment: Not sure, is there a definition of *subexpression*? As far as I can tell, §1.9p10 defines *full-expression* rather than *subexpression* (though the wording "of another expression" might indicate that indeed subexpression is `<=` rather than `<`) -- that was point two I wanted to address. Point one is that the statements within the function are not subexpressions of the function call expression. -- oh, and happy Towel Day ;)

Comment: @dyp There is no definition, but I'd assume that what you mentioned is indeed the case. To point two: Yeah, I think I'll need to reword that. But what about /11: *"The evaluation of a full-expression can include the evaluation of subexpressions that are not **lexically part of the full-expression**."* This indicates that an expression can be a subexpression of `f()` without lexically appearing within it.

Comment: I'm not sure that one can conclude that the expressions within the function `f` are subexpressions of `f()` from that paragraph: It talks about the *evaluation* of expressions, it doesn't say that those become/are part of `f()`.

Comment: @dyp Maybe we need to more subtly distinguish between lexical and evaluative subexpressions. I'll file an issue.

Comment: @dyp It appears the term subexpression is used consistently as < and not <=, e.g.: "A subexpression `e1` of an expression `e` is an immediate subexpression if there is no subexpression
`e2` of `e` such that `e1` is a subexpression of `e2`." can be found in [\[except.spec\]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#12). Mea culpa.