# how do I assert from constexpr function with exceptions disabled?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, metaprogramming, constexpr

If I want to assert a detected error from a C++11 constexpr function in a small processor embedded design turning off interrupts takes away the suggested method of handling errors (see eric nieblers answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072709/alternative-to-asserts-for-constexpr-functions))

Here is a short code example:

```
constexpr bool isANumber(char c)
{
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}

constexpr int charToInt(char c)
{
    return (!isANumber(c))? throw std::logic_error("not a number"):
        c - '0';
}
```

To the best of my knowledge:

- static_assert is not allowed because the inputs could be run time values
- assert may force the function to be run time evaluated and the assert handler drags in so much stuff that it will overflow the flash memory of most Cortex chips
- throw will not work because I turned off exceptions

What is the work around?

**Note:** Using C++ in super resource constrained embedded environments one must turn off exceptions because they use excess RAM (my chip has only 16K RAM for example). It is common practice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437431/is-assert-usable-in-constant-expressions

Comment: In C++14 you're allowed to `assert` in `constexpr` functions.

Comment: @101010 thanks for the comment, I need it on C++11 though, added that to my question

Comment: @columbo thanks for the link, looks like my question may be a duplicate

Comment: looks like assert is also not an option because the GCC assert drags so much stuff into the binary that I would not fit on most ARM Cortex chips

Comment: How do you "assert"-equivalent in a non-constexpr function on your platform?  It isn't *that* hard to convert almost any runtime handler to a `constexpr`-conditionally-safe one, but without a solution for non-`constexpr` I'm not sure what you expect.

Comment: "assert"-equivalent is calling a hard fault handler who's functionality is customizeable but usually triggers a breakpoint or resets the system. Thats why I would rather push the error to compile time.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for the special case the you can guarantee that your constexpr function will never be called at runtime. In that case you can just force a non constant evaluation error.

```
int assert_failed() {
    static int i = 5;
    return i++;
}
constexpr int cheap_assert(bool i) {
    return i == 1 ? 0 : assert_failed();
}

constexpr unsigned operator""_my_literal(const char* s, std::size_t size) {
    return cheap_assert(size < 10), 0;
}
```

Comment: @Orient not on MSVC2015, but I think your right and its probably a microsoft bug